# Admission webhook pod update

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, mutate

Is it possible to mutate environment variables in kubernetes pod with admission control webhook that is triggered by UPDATE operation?

Is there way to see how patch from mutate webhook is applied?

The thing is I am able to update metadata but my environment variables are not updated. When I apply it on CREATE operation it works just fine.

Comment: A mutating admission webhook should be able to make pretty much any change in an object it observes.  Can you share your existing webhook code, and further describe the trouble you're running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to mutate environment variables with admission control on UPDATE operation.

Source:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#pod-update-and-replacement